# Can Blender Internal Render passes be put back together again?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm stuck with a simple task. I need to tweak some render passes of the image, and then put them back to the combined composited image. For Cycles I use this scheme from the manual:
[image: cycles scheme]

It works as intended.

But I cannot figure out a way to do the same trick in the Blender Render. So, I can tick some passes to be rendered separately, and I can exclude those passes from the combined pass. Like this:

[image: bi-passes-settings]

What I cannot do, is mixing them back to get the final image.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved in the blender internal render engine?